Directus 10.12 – flow to slugify a field returns permission error
The following flow and scripts are based on a video tutorial by the Directus team on their channel! I tried to rebuild it, but I fail not knowing where the error is.
The contact page (and others) in my Directus 10.12.1 instance uses a header field, the content of which should automatically be "sluggified". To do so I set up a Contact collection with the essential fields "title" and "slug" (and some others) like this:

, add permissions

, and create the flow:

The first step in the flow "Create slug" is an non-blocking "Event Hook" with the items.create and items.update scopes selected and assigned to various collections:

The 2nd step in the flow is a "Run Script" operation with the name "Slugify me" and the key slugify_me (which is essential for the update process); it contains this script:
module.exports = async function (data) {
  // Index data to get the string you want to slugify
  // Assign it to the "text" var below.
  const text = data.$trigger.payload.title;

  const slug = text
    //.normalize('NFD')
    .replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, '')
    .toLowerCase()
    .trim()
    .replace(/[^\w\s-]/g, '')
    .replace(/[\s_-]+/g, '-')
    .replace(/^-+|-+$/g, '');

  return slug;
};


Next I added a simple "Log to console" operation to inspect the content of $trigger and $operation_key:

The last step in the flow is supposed to update the slug field using the "Update Data" operation. The payload script uses the slugify_me key from the "Run script" step and looks like this:
{
  "slug": "{{ slugify_me }}"
}


However, when I edit the contact page the logs return the following in the "Update the slug" step:
// Options
{
  "collection": "contact",
  "key": "undefined",
  "payload": {
    "slug": "contact-me-now"
  }
}

// Payload
{
  "name": "DirectusError",
  "message": "You don't have permission to access this."
}

and consequently in the "Error log" (that is connected to the "Update" operation on the return false output):
// Error on update
{
  "message": "Error Step 3 - update:  {\"event\":\"contact.items.update\",\"payload\":{\"subtitle\":\"I am always eager to read from you!\",\"title\":\"Contact me now!\"},\"keys\":[\"1\"],\"collection\":\"contact\"}, undefined"
}


I have no clue, why this script does not work. Anybody can spot the error?
